# sql query results display question marks from javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server

I have js code in .asp file with connection to `sql server` , execute query and respones resultes of the query.
i inserted charset = `"utf-8"` or `"Windows-1255"` and it still didnt work.
my database collation is hebrew_ci_as and most of my data in all the tables is hebrew.

every time i try to get the results of the query with one Request.QueryString parameter on web or in my application i get question marks (????) instead of all the hebrew strings , the english is fine and the integers are fine.

i am in `windows server 2012 r2` standart that have hebrew and english , `sql server 2008 r2`,`iis 6.2` with all the updates.

THE JS CODE:

```
    Response.Expires        =   -1;
    Response.CharSet        =   "Windows-1255";


var user_id             =   new String(Request.QueryString("user_id"));
var strConnection       =   new String("PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ABC;Initial Catalog=DEF;uid=GHI;pwd=JKL");
var query               =   new String("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE contact.identifier = '"+user_id+"'");

var cnn =   Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
var adClipString =  2;
        if(user_id.toLowerCase()!="undefined")
    {
        try
        {
            cnn.Open(strConnection);
            query=query.replace(/%user_id%/i,user_id);

            var returnVal   =   cnn.Execute(query).GetString(adClipString,-1,"@@@","","")

            Response.Write(returnVal)


        }
        catch(e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cnn.State==1)cnn.Close();
            cnn=null;
        }
    };
```

THE RESULT:

`@@@@@@03-1234567@@@ItzikE@@@?????@@@?????@@@59 ???? , ?? ???? - ???@@@?? ???? - ???@@@??? ???? ??????? ????@@@114@@@0@@@moital@@@moital@@@?????, ?????`

all the hebrew is `???` , i used this code many times in many different environments and servers and i solved this problem allways by saving the file itself with `utf-8` format in any editor like - `pspad`,`notepad++`... and it allways worked .
this time its somthing else that i realy tried everything and dont know.
help,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it - just changed the timezone LOL ))

Answer (score 1):

replace this line

```
 new String("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE contact.identifier = '"+user_id+"'");
```

from this and check

```
 new String("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE contact.identifier = N'"+user_id+"'");
```

> You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server

**Reference: [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530)**

Comment: yeah i know about the National language character set , i forgot to mention it didn't work also :)

Comment: when i execute the query in the sql manager itself with N or without N  its displays the results always good , but when i execute the query from the js code on internet explorer with link or from html code with path only then the results are ????.  i am not sure but i think maybe the problem is in windows,iis,sql manager or internet explorer becouse the same code for the same database in my vmware on my laptop is working fine.